# Removing duplicate rows in R based upon a factor variable

Tags: r, filter, dplyr, duplicates, distinct

I am attempting to remove duplicate rows based upon the presence of a factor variable. If the factor variable in the duplicated row shows *desired*, rather than *not desired*, I would like to keep that row and remove the other row. The factor desired will sometimes appear as the first duplicate and sometimes as the second.

In addition, there is a column that begins counting for thirty days once **either** desired or not desired pops up. In the absence of type (NA), the duplicate flag column will also show NA.

In the end, there should be 1 row per brand per day.

A sample of the data at hand:

```
brand    date      sales orders customers   type        duplicate_flag
A     10/1/2018    100    5       4         NA                 NA
A     10/2/2018    150    8       6        desired             1
A     10/2/2018    150    8       6        not desired         1
A     10/3/2018    110    5       4          NA                2
```

Desired output:

```
brand    date      sales orders customers   type        duplicate_flag
A     10/1/2018    100    5       4         NA                 NA
A     10/2/2018    150    8       6        desired             1
A     10/3/2018    110    5       4          NA                2
```

If there is a way to do this in dplyr, that would be great.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some usable sample data.

```
df <-
  data_frame(
    Date = c(1,2,2,3,3,4)
    , Metric = 1:6
    , type = c(NA, "desired", "not desired", "not desired", "desired", "not desired")
  )
```

Which looks like:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 3
   Date Metric type       
  <dbl>  <int> <chr>      
1     1      1 <NA>       
2     2      2 desired    
3     2      3 not desired
4     3      4 not desired
5     3      5 desired    
6     4      6 not desired
```

I am assuming that you want to keep one row per date, based on the `type` column, but that the other columns may (or may not) differ from each other. (If they never differ from each other, I don't see why it would matter which row you keep.)

For that, the simplest is probably to sort the data by `type` (ensuring that the value you want to keep comes first -- you may have to change `type` to a factor with the "desired" value as the first level if it is not the first alphabetically for some reason) then use `slice` to keep the first entry.

```
df %>%
  arrange(type) %>%
  group_by(Date) %>%
  slice(1) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  arrange(Date)
```

returns:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 3
   Date Metric type       
  <dbl>  <int> <chr>      
1     1      1 <NA>       
2     2      2 desired    
3     3      5 desired    
4     4      6 not desired
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume your dataframe is "df"

```
df %>% filter(type != "not desired" | is.na(type))
```

Or

```
df %>% select(-type) %>% distinct()
```

Comment: This gets close but there will be times when I want to keep the "not desired", so long as it is not a duplicate with "desired."

Comment: `df %>% group_by_at(vars(-type)) %>% summarise(type = "desired") `